# Python program that stops looping and gets stuck randomly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying hard to learn Python for some time now and I'm stuck trying to make this simple program work.

As you can see, what I'm trying to do is get 4 values to 'battle' until one is left. It goes fine and dandy until anywhere from loop #11 to #22, and then it just stops. I'm a complete beginner, and dont know what I'm doing wrong.

```
import random
import math
import os

print '     ----------------------------------'
print '       UNIVERSAL ALL-STARS DEATHMATCH'
print '     ----------------------------------'
print ''
print 'CHOOSE FOUR CHARACTERS TO FIGHT IN AN FFA DEATHMATCH!'
print ''

#User input for character names.
characterInputted = False
while characterInputted == False:
    character1 = raw_input('Input Character 1 Name:')
    character2 = raw_input('Input Character 2 Name:')
    character3 = raw_input('Input Character 3 Name:')
    character4 = raw_input('Input Character 4 Name:')
    if character1 == character2:
        print 'Cannot have any characters with identical names!'
        characterInputted = False
    elif character1 == character3:
        print 'Cannot have any characters with identical names!'
        characterInputted = False
    elif character1 == character4:
        print 'Cannot have any characters with identical names!'
        characterInputted = False
    elif character2 == character3:
        print 'Cannot have any characters with identical names!'
        characterInputted = False
    elif character2 == character4:
        print 'Cannot have any characters with identical names!'
        characterInputted = False
    elif character3 == character4:
        print 'Cannot have any characters with identical names!'
        characterInputted = False
    else:
        characterInputted = True

def combat_roll():
    combatValid = False
    while combatValid == False:
        rollAtk = random.randint(1, 4)
        rollDef = random.randint(1, 4)
        if rollAtk == rollDef:
            combatValid = False
#Roll for char1
        elif rollAtk == character1_Number:
            if character1_Dead == True:
                combatValid = False
            elif rollDef == character2_Number:
                if character2_Dead == True:
                    combatValid = False
                else:
                    rollAttacker = character1
                    rollDefender = character2
                    combatValid = True
                    return rollAttacker, rollDefender
            elif rollDef == character3_Number:
                if character3_Dead == True:
                    combatValid = False
                else:
                    rollAttacker = character1
                    rollDefender = character3
                    combatValid = True
                    return rollAttacker, rollDefender
            elif rollDef == character4_Number:
                if character4_Dead == True:
                    combatValid = False
                else:
                    rollAttacker = character1
                    rollDefender = character4
                    combatValid = True
                    return rollAttacker, rollDefender
#Roll for char2
        elif rollAtk == character2_Number:
            if character2_Dead == True:
                combatValid = False
            elif rollDef == character1_Number:
                if character1_Dead == True:
                    combatValid = False
                else:
                    rollAttacker = character2
                    rollDefender = character1
                    combatValid = True
                    return rollAttacker, rollDefender
            elif rollDef == character3_Number:
                if character3_Dead == True:
                    combatValid = False
                else:
                    rollAttacker = character2
                    rollDefender = character3
                    combatValid = True
                    return rollAttacker, rollDefender
            elif rollDef == character4_Number:
                if character4_Dead == True:
                    combatValid = False
                else:
                    rollAttacker = character2
                    rollDefender = character4
                    combatValid = True
                    return rollAttacker, rollDefender
#Roll for char3
        elif rollAtk == character3_Number:
            if character1_Dead == True:
                combatValid = False
            elif rollDef == character1_Number:
                if character2_Dead == True:
                    combatValid = False
                else:
                    rollAttacker = character3
                    rollDefender = character1
                    combatValid = True
                    return rollAttacker, rollDefender
            elif rollDef == character2_Number:
                if character2_Dead == True:
                    combatValid = False
                else:
                    rollAttacker = character3
                    rollDefender = character2
                    combatValid = True
                    return rollAttacker, rollDefender
            elif rollDef == character4_Number:
                if character4_Dead == True:
                    combatValid = False
                else:
                    rollAttacker = character3
                    rollDefender = character4
                    combatValid = True
                    return rollAttacker, rollDefender
#Roll for char4
        elif rollAtk == character4_Number:
            if character1_Dead == True:
                combatValid = False
            elif rollDef == character1_Number:
                if character1_Dead == True:
                    combatValid = False
                else:
                    rollAttacker = character4
                    rollDefender = character1
                    combatValid = True
                    return rollAttacker, rollDefender
            elif rollDef == character2_Number:
                if character2_Dead == True:
                    combatValid = False
                else:
                    rollAttacker = character4
                    rollDefender = character2
                    combatValid = True
                    return rollAttacker, rollDefender
            elif rollDef == character3_Number:
                if character3_Dead == True:
                    combatValid = False
                else:
                    rollAttacker = character4
                    rollDefender = character3
                    combatValid = True
                    return rollAttacker, rollDefender
        else:
            combatValid = False

#Roundtick set to zero
roundNumber = 0

#Characters randomly generated stats.
character1_Attackbonus = random.randint(0, 2)
character1_Number = 1
character1_Dead = False
character1_LifeCount = 1

character2_Attackbonus = random.randint(0, 2)
character2_Number = 2
character2_Dead = False
character2_LifeCount = 1

character3_Attackbonus = random.randint(0, 2)
character3_Number = 3
character3_Dead = False
character3_LifeCount = 1

character4_Attackbonus = random.randint(0, 2)
character4_Number = 4
character4_Dead = False
character4_LifeCount = 1

gameover = False
while gameover == False:
    os.system('cls')
    lifeCount_Total = [character1_LifeCount +
                       character2_LifeCount + character3_LifeCount +
                       character4_LifeCount]
    roundNumber = roundNumber + 1
    print 'Round #%d!' % roundNumber
    raw_input('Press ENTER to continue.')
    attackChance = random.randint(0, 10)
    if lifeCount_Total > 2 == True:
        gameover = True
    elif attackChance < 3:
        print "No one attacked this round!"
    elif attackChance > 3:
        Attacker, Defender = combat_roll()
        print Attacker + ' attacked ' + Defender + '.'
        Attackbase = random.randint(0, 10)
#Combat calculations!
        combatCalc = False
        while combatCalc == False:
            if Attacker == character1:
                AttackTotal = Attackbase + character1_Attackbonus
                if Defender == character2:
                    if AttackTotal > 5:
                        character2_Dead = True
                        character2_LifeCount = 0
                        print '%s killed %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                    else:
                        print '%s failed to kill %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                elif Defender == character3:
                    if AttackTotal > 5:
                        character3_Dead = True
                        character3_LifeCount = 0
                        print '%s killed %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                    else:
                        print '%s failed to kill %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                    combatCalc = True
                elif Defender == character4:
                    if AttackTotal > 5:
                        character4_Dead = True
                        character4_LifeCount = 0
                        print '%s killed %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                    else:
                        print '%s failed to kill %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True

            elif Attacker == character2:
                AttackTotal = Attackbase + character2_Attackbonus
                if Defender == character1:
                    if AttackTotal > 5:
                        character1_Dead = True
                        character1_LifeCount = 0
                        print '%s killed %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                    else:
                        print '%s failed to kill %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                elif Defender == character3:
                    if AttackTotal > 5:
                        character3_Dead = True
                        character3_LifeCount = 0
                        print '%s killed %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                    else:
                        print '%s failed to kill %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                    combatCalc = True
                elif Defender == character4:
                    if AttackTotal > 5:
                        character4_Dead = True
                        character4_LifeCount = 0
                        print '%s killed %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                    else:
                        print '%s failed to kill %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True

            elif Attacker == character3:
                AttackTotal = Attackbase + character3_Attackbonus
                if Defender == character1:
                    if AttackTotal > 5:
                        character1_Dead = True
                        character1_LifeCount = 0
                        print '%s killed %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                    else:
                        print '%s failed to kill %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                elif Defender == character2:
                    if AttackTotal > 5:
                        character2_Dead = True
                        character2_LifeCount = 0
                        print '%s killed %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                    else:
                        print '%s failed to kill %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                    combatCalc = True
                elif Defender == character4:
                    if AttackTotal > 5:
                        character4_Dead = True
                        character4_LifeCount = 0
                        print '%s killed %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                    else:
                        print '%s failed to kill %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True

            elif Attacker == character4:
                AttackTotal = Attackbase + character4_Attackbonus
                if Defender == character1:
                    if AttackTotal > 5:
                        character1_Dead = True
                        character1_LifeCount = 0
                        print '%s killed %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                    else:
                        print '%s failed to kill %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                elif Defender == character2:
                    if AttackTotal > 5:
                        character2_Dead = True
                        character2_LifeCount = 0
                        print '%s killed %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                    else:
                        print '%s failed to kill %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                    combatCalc = True
                elif Defender == character3:
                    if AttackTotal > 5:
                        character3_Dead = True
                        character3_LifeCount = 0
                        print '%s killed %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
                    else:
                        print '%s failed to kill %s!' % (Attacker, Defender)
                        combatCalc = True
            else:
                combatCalc = False        
    else:
        gameover = False

print character1
print character2
print character3
print character4
```

Comment: You might want to use Pycharm and its debugger (there are other tools like it, i just happen to use this). It will help you track all values step by step.

Comment: What do you mean "it just stops"? Is it repeating a loop, or just quits the game?

Comment: Note that you haven't specified an action in case `attackChance == 3`.

Comment: I'll look up Pycharm, in the meantime I'll have to look through the code.

And when I say it just stops, I mean it gets stuck on a round and doesn't go forward.

Answer (score -1):

I tested your code and it seems that it doesn't stop but enter in the function `combat_roll()` and is stuck in it. If I print `combatValid`, I obtain :

```
`false 
 false
 false
 ...
```

Comment: Hum... Thats a good job of narrowing it down. It just prints false, huh?